# Statically casting an integer to pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, type-conversion

I just can't find out how this simple example can be compiled in C++ :

```
class C
{
  public:
    static const void* noop = static_cast<const void*> (0x1);
};
```

Because of the `static` storage constraint I want, the only cast possible here would be `static_cast` but it is incompatible with this int-to-ptr cast.

> error: invalid static_cast from type ‘int’ to type ‘const void*’

How can an integer value be statically casted to a pointer type?

Comment: You're getting a descriptive error with your `static_cast`, I bet.  Can you share it?

Comment: how about [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df7f9e0b0edb48dc)

Comment: This code doesn't work for me even if I try to assign NULL instead of 0x1. It gives `error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line` (clang++)

Comment: Have you tried `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: As I state in my answer it seems like using `intptr_t` leads to a  better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that although you are declaring a `const void*` the `const` qualifier doesn't apply to the pointer but to the address that this pointer points to.

This means that `noop` is not a `static const` member variable and as all non `const static` member variables needs to be defined and initialized in a single translation unit outside `class`'s definition like the example below:

```
class C {
  public:
    static const void *noop;
};

const void* C::noop = (const void*) 0x1;
```

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8efab5c4ebd485d3)**

The following solution:

```
class C {
public:
  static constexpr const void* noop = reinterpret_cast<const void*>(0x1);
};
```

Although, it compiles and works fine in GCC isn't valid C++ (e.g., it doesn't compile with either clang or VC++2013) because according to the standard *§ 5.19/2 Constant Expressions [expr.const]* **the result of a `reinterpret_cast` can't be a constant expression.**

Comment: Also, why did you make the variable non-const?

Comment: @BenVoigt in the example provided by the OP is non-const.

Comment: @40two: Sorry, I spent too much time looking at the `constexpr` attempts.

Answer (score 3):

`reinterpret_cast` is what you are looking for (raw interpretation of the bytes of an `int` to a `const void*` pointer)

Also, you need `constexpr` for in-class initialization of static data member :

```
class C
{
  public:
    static constexpr const void* noop = reinterpret_cast<const void*>(0x1);
};
```

`static_cast` doesn't work since there is no combination of user-defined or implicit conversions that would transform an `int` to a `const void*`.

**EDIT:**

This solution is not standard C++ (`reinterpret_cast` is not allowed in constant expressions), 40two [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24398667/3510483)'s is correct.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Nope: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/685b3b1ee008f14c.  It needs both.

Comment: I missed the `constexpr` ! C++11 gives me headache... Thank you !

Comment: @quantdev No, it's a pointer to a `const void` but the pointer is non-const.

Comment: This is wrong the result of `reinterpret_cast` is never a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

40two has fixed the compile error, but also made the member non-`const`, which is undesirable because it hinders optimization and opens to door to accidental mutation.

Best:

```
class C {
  public:
    static const void* const noop;
};

const void* const C::noop = reinterpret_cast<const void*>(0x1);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution which also comes from the question *40two* references: [constexpr and initialization of a static const void pointer with reinterpret cast, which compiler is right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398102/1708801), is to use [intptr_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) which is:

> integer type capable of holding a pointer

This also allows you to make the member variable a [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

```
class C
{
  public:
    static constexpr intptr_t noop = 0x1 ;
};
```

then you can use *reinterpret_cast* at the point where it is used:

```
const void * vPtr = reinterpret_cast<void*>( C::noop ) ;
```