# Passing an IO register as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, avr

I want to use an IO-Register ( == static memory address ) as a template parameter. The problem is, that registers are commonly defined as macros expanding to something similar to `(*(volatile uint8_t*)(11 + 0x20))` which I somehow cannot get to work with my templates properly.

I would like to write code like:

```
Foo<PORTB> foo;
```

That way I can easily change the IO register the class uses without any runtime overhead (which is crucial for microcontrollers).
I have included a full example below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

#define PORTB  (*(volatile uint8_t*)(11 + 0x20))

template<volatile uint8_t* PortRegister>
class ControllerPtr final
{
public:
    static void SetHigh() { *PortRegister |= 0x2; }
};

template<volatile uint8_t& PortRegister>
class ControllerRef final
{
public:
    static void SetHigh() { PortRegister |= 0x2; }
};


int main()
{
    ControllerPtr<&PORTB> ptr;
    ControllerRef<PORTB> ref;

    ptr.SetHigh();
    ref.SetHigh();

    // Both statements should be equal to:
    // PORTB |= 0x2;
}
```

Everytime when I try to pass `&PORTB` to `ControllerPtr`, g++ fails to compile:

> error: `(volatile uint8_t*)((long int)(11 + 32))` is not a valid template argument for `volatile uint8_t* {aka volatile unsigned char*}` because it is not the address of a variable
>
> error: expression `*(volatile uint8_t*)((long int)(11 + 32))` has side-effects

The error is a little bit different when trying to pass `PORTB` to a reference type like used in `ControllerRef`:

> error: `*(volatile uint8_t*)((long int)(11 + 32))` is not a valid template argument for type `volatile uint8_t& {aka volatile unsigned char&}` because it is not an object with linkage

I actually don't understand why this error is an error, as I don't see any problem with passing static addresses to templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non-type template parameter has to be a constant expression, and you cannot have a `reinterpret_cast` inside a constant expression (unless it is unevaluated).

Since you've indicated that you have no way of getting access to the numeric address other than through macros such as `PORTB`, I suggest a workaround. Though `PORTB` cannot be used in a template parameter, we can synthesize a unique type that can be used in a template parameter, like so:

```
struct PORTB_tag {
    static volatile uint8_t& value() { return PORTB; }
};
template <class PortTag>
class ControllerRef final {
  public:
    static void SetHigh() { PortTag::value() |= 0x2; }
};
int main() {
    ControllerRef<PORTB_tag> ref;
    ref.SetHigh();
}
```

To save repetitive typing when you have lots of ports, we can use macros:

```
#define PORT_TAG(port) port_tag_for_ ## port
#define MAKE_PORT_TAG(port) struct port_tag_for_ ## port { \
    static volatile uint8_t& value() { return port; } \
}
template <class PortTag>
class ControllerRef final {
  public:
    static void SetHigh() { PortTag::value() |= 0x2; }
};
MAKE_PORT_TAG(PORTB);
int main() {
    ControllerRef<PORT_TAG(PORTB)> ref;
    ref.SetHigh();
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/401c0847d77ec0e0

Comment: This isn't actually possible, since I have no direct access to the underlying address of register defines like `PORTB`. Those are macros which only ultimately evaluate to e.g. `*(volatile uint8_t*)(11 + 0x20)`. I cannot change them and have to use the macro to obtain the address. So in your example I would need a way to declare the `constexpr portb` variable only by using `PORTB` and not the address it evaluates to.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian pointed out in his answer, the template parameter has to be a constant expression.  In somewhat older GCCs (pre-6.0), the following **hack** should work:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

#define PORTB (*(volatile uint8_t*)(11 + 0x20))

// Helper constant for 0 address
#define ZERO  (*(volatile uint8_t*)(0))

// A ptrdiff_t is OK
template <std::ptrdiff_t PortRegister>
class ControllerPtr final
{
public:
  // Get back to the actual desired address
  static void SetHigh() { *(volatile uint8_t*)(&ZERO+PortRegister) |= 0x2; }
};

// Define helper constants for all relevant registers
static constexpr std::ptrdiff_t C_PORTB = &PORTB-&ZERO;

int main()
{
  // Now this works
  ControllerPtr<C_PORTB> ptr;

  ptr.SetHigh();
}
```

[Inspect the result here](https://godbolt.org/g/ZDD0UM).  I'm calling it a hack because newer GCC versions will (rightly) refuse to compile this with the error

> error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer

at the line of the `constexpr` declaration, because technically you cannot use the result of a `reinterpret_cast` in a constant expression.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397797/statically-casting-an-integer-to-pointer-type) provides a bit more background.